# Spring Cloud Contract, Openapi with contract extension

Tags: openapi, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to run Spring Cloud Contract Stub runner as a Spring Boot server application (@EnableStubRunnerServer). Also I wanted to use OpenApi yaml specification with contract extension by Springframeworkguru, with oas3 converter.

But that setup does  not work. When I try to boot the Spring Boot app (java -jar ...), it fails with exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "openapi" (class org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.converter.YamlContract), not marked as ignorable (10 known properties: "response", "ignored", "metaClass", "label", "outputMessage", "input", "name", "description", "request", "priority"])
```

Obviously (?) the reason of this error is openapi.yml file, that is also included in generated stubs jar.

I am hoping that someone could come up with a solution. Spring Cloud Contract stub server deployed as Spring Boot app would be really nice and agile way to set up/deploy a stub server. And also today the use of "contract first" with OpenApi 3 spec is a requirement in all projects.

I'm using the classpath option, so the stubs jar is included in Spring Boot application dependencies (in fat jar).

ADDED LOG with part of stacktrace. Contracts get generated ok and can be found in target directory.

```
2020-03-02 11:24:12.098  INFO 89835 --- [           main] c.example.sccoas31.SccOas31Application   : Starting SccOas31Application on XXXXXXX-MacBook-Air.local with PID 89835 (/Users/ok/dev/spring-cloud-contract/oa3-example/scc-oas3-1/target/classes started by ok in /Users/ok/dev/spring-cloud-contract/oa3-example/scc-oas3-1)
2020-03-02 11:24:12.109  INFO 89835 --- [           main] c.example.sccoas31.SccOas31Application   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-02 11:24:14.128  INFO 89835 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'stubrunner-org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerProperties' of type [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-02 11:24:14.131  INFO 89835 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a516edc8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-02 11:24:14.164  INFO 89835 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.s.ClasspathStubProvider          : Will download stubs from classpath
2020-03-02 11:24:14.310  WARN 89835 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunnerBeanPostProcessor' defined in org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'batchStubRunnerBeanPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunner' defined in org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No stubs were found on classpath for [com.example:scc-oas3-1]
2020-03-02 11:24:14.323  INFO 89835 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-02 11:24:14.348 ERROR 89835 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunnerBeanPostProcessor' defined in org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'batchStubRunnerBeanPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunner' defined in org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No stubs were found on classpath for [com.example:scc-oas3-1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.sccoas31.SccOas31Application.main(SccOas31Application.java:16) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchStubRunner' defined in org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No stubs were found on classpath for [com.example:scc-oas3-1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunner]: Factory method 'batchStubRunner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No stubs were found on classpath for [com.example:scc-oas3-1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No stubs were found on classpath for [com.example:scc-oas3-1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.ClasspathStubProvider$1.downloadAndUnpackStubJar(ClasspathStubProvider.java:101) ~[spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.CompositeStubDownloader.downloadAndUnpackStubJar(CompositeStubDownloaderBuilder.java:80) ~[spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.StubRunnerFactory.createStubsFromServiceConfiguration(StubRunnerFactory.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.BatchStubRunnerFactory.buildBatchStubRunner(BatchStubRunnerFactory.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration.batchStubRunner(StubRunnerConfiguration.java:84) ~[spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a516edc8.CGLIB$batchStubRunner$0(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a516edc8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5a4ce29b.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.spring.StubRunnerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a516edc8.batchStubRunner(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60216', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

--- pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>scc-oas3-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>scc-oas3-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>scc-oas3-1</artifactId>
            <classifier>stubs</classifier>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-oa3</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>

                <dependencies>
                    <!--needed to include oa3 converter-->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-oa3</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are your sure it's failing because of this or just printing out the log. Anything else is there in the stacktrace?

Comment: I added bigger part of log, is that of any help?

Comment: "No stubs were found on classpath for [com.example:scc-oas3-1]" it seems that the extension wasn't properly setup and it couldn't fetch the stubs.

Comment: I added pom, does it seem to be OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stub mappings jar packages generated using 
Spring Cloud Contract OpenAPI 3.0 Contract Converter (by springframeworkguru)

when used with Spring Boot app with @EnableStubRunnerServer
requires Spring Cloud Hoxton release.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your POM it seems that you're mixing the test and production dependencies. Since you want to use a Spring Cloud Contract Server you need to have all the dependencies in compile scope. Moreover, you're using a maven plugin. Maven plugin should be used if you want to generate tests from your contracts, whereas you want to only run stubs (so you should remove the plugin).

Sth like this should work I guess (of course please upgrade to the latest GA versions)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>scc-oas3-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>scc-oas3-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>scc-oas3-1</artifactId>
            <classifier>stubs</classifier>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-oa3</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: OK, thanks.

My stupid mistake. It kind of seemed that the same build can first generate stubs jar, and after that add the same stubs.jar as (runtime) maven dependency in order to run the project. It seemed to work because I already had that stub jar (same name) in local maven repo.

Comment: I just can't find a way to use stub jar created by OAS3 converter with Spring Cloud Contract stub runner. Stub runner can't deal with openapi.yml file that is "left" in stub jar file. "Unrecognized field openapi ... ..." Too bad.

Comment: If I delete openapi.yml from stub jar file, Spring Cloud Contract stub runner works fine. But delete one file from inside a jar file is not a viable solution when using automated pipelines.

Comment: Please use the latest ga release of spring cloud. Imo it's a bug that has already been fixed

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot Stub Runner works ok with Hoxton.SR2, I tested it using Ubuntu linux. - But on Windows 10  Hoxton scc "boot stub server" does not seem work at all ?!? Just tested also with Win 10 and Hoxton.SR3.